# ¿Cómo sanitizar los valores de campos que se guardan en una matriz multidimensional?

Tags: php, wordpress

Tengo un formulario con campos y guardo sus valores en una matriz multidimensional, me interesa sanitizar los valores antes de guardar. Me han comentado que use un bucle foreach antes de guardar pero no encuentro documentación al respecto para hacerlo. Quisiera aplicar por ejemplo sanitize_textarea_field () al campo textarea y sanitize_text_field() para sanitizar los campos ocultos.

```
<form id="propvendor"method="post" action="">

<input type="hidden" id="porc_05" name="porc_05[date]" value="<?php echo $current_date;?>">

<input type="hidden" id="porc_05" name="porc_05[id]" value="<?php echo $id_current;?>">

<textarea placeholder="Comentarios..." id="porc_05" name="porc_05[comment]"></textarea>


<input type="hidden" id="pointspossible" value="<?php echo $price;?>"/>

<select name="porc_05[perce]"style="background: #fff;"id="pointsgiven" >
   <option value="0">0%</option>
    <option value="5">5%</option>
    <option value="10">10%</option>
    <option value="15">15%</option>
    <option value="20">20%</option>
    <option value="25">25%</option>
  </select>


<input style="border: none;padding: 0px;color:black;"type="number" id="pointsperc" disabled/>


<button style="border-radius: 4px;"name="si_prop" type="submit" value=""><i class="fas fa-check"></i></button>

</form>
```

Así los guardo actualmente, sin sanitizar:

```
if(isset($_POST['si_prop'])){
if(isset($_POST['porc_05'])){

$array = $_POST['porc_05'];
add_post_meta( $prod_id, 'propina5', $array, $unique );  

$data = get_post_meta($prod_id, 'propina5', $single);  
}
}
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! desinfectar, querra decir sanitizar?

Comment: Hola, gracias por tu respuesta. tienes razón es sanitizar exactamente. Por cierto, ahora leeré esos artículos, gracias nuevamente

Comment: cuando los hayas leído puede editar tu post y mejorarlo con eso puede que reciba mejor aceptación y respuesta de parte de los programadores de php y Wordpress.

Comment: Que está mal ahora en mi pregunta? La había corregido antes de tu comentario @Arcanis-TheOmnipotent

Comment: no he dicho que algo esta mal ... te decia que editandola y agregando lo que te piden los usuarios puede que recibas mas apoyo ..

Comment: Entiendo, si estoy totalmente de acuerdo y le agradezco mucho su apoyo!

Answer (score 0):

Según la documentación de wordpress las funciones que mencionas para sanitizar se ven así:

```
function sanitize_text_field( $str ) {
    $filtered = _sanitize_text_fields( $str, false );
 
    /**
     * Filters a sanitized text field string.
     *
     * @since 2.9.0
     *
     * @param string $filtered The sanitized string.
     * @param string $str      The string prior to being sanitized.
     */
    return apply_filters( 'sanitize_text_field', $filtered, $str );
}

function sanitize_textarea_field( $str ) {
    $filtered = _sanitize_text_fields( $str, true );
 
    /**
     * Filters a sanitized textarea field string.
     *
     * @since 4.7.0
     *
     * @param string $filtered The sanitized string.
     * @param string $str      The string prior to being sanitized.
     */
    return apply_filters( 'sanitize_textarea_field', $filtered, $str );
}
```

Puedes ver la documentación de [sanitize_textarea_field](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/sanitize_textarea_field/) y [sanitize_text_field](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/sanitize_text_field/).

Basado en dicha documentación solo basta con pasar el respectivo string a la función que desees.

Ahora, si nos basamos en tu código podemos unificar las condicionales para evitar un doble if.

```
if(isset($_POST['si_prop']) && isset($_POST['porc_05'])){

}
```

y dentro podemos sanitizar una variable que contenga el texto directamente con la respectiva función:

EJ:

```
    $text_sanitized = sanitize_text_field($YOUR_UNSANITIZED_VAR);
```

Si el contenido que deseas sanitizar está dentro de un array clave-valor simplemente utiliza un ciclo como `foreach`.

EJ:

```
$elements = ["first_field" => 1 , "second_field" => 2 , "third_field" => 3];

foreach($elements as $key => $value){
    $elements[$key] = sanitize_text_field($value);
}
```

Si deseas sanitizar las claves en vez de los valores te recomiendo guardar todo en un nuevo `array` y luego sobrescribir el original.
Ej:

```
$elements = ["first_field" => 1 , "second_field" => 2 , "third_field" => 3];
$temp = array();
foreach($elements as $key => $value){
    $temp[sanitize_text_field($key)] = $value;
}
$elements = $temp;
```

y si lo que tienes es un objeto, puedes castearlo a array para sanitizarlo y volverlo nuevamente a objeto anteponiendo el tipo de dato deseado.
Ej;

hacerlo array:

```
$some_object_as_array = (array) $some_object;
```

hacerlo objeto de nuevo:

```
$some_object = (object) $some_object_as_array;
```

Creo que llegado a este punto, tienes las herramientas necesarias para armar todo por tu cuenta!